# Import statements are showing erros in flutter project, but working fine in an individual project

Tags: android, flutter

I am getting the errors (related to android import statement)like below in flutter project. but if I open the same android project separately in the android studio it was not showing any errors(import statements not showing any errors). Any fixes??
[image]

Flutter Activity import statement is not impcolouredproperly means showing with red colored import statement saying that unused import statement

[image]

Comment: Please add code instead of code snapshots

Comment: @Maddy, the attached image will be enough i think to point out the issue. There is bunch of code to add here thats the problem for me. Actually the problem is with import statements in flutter not in individual android project.

Comment: Then put the code which is required, attach required screenshots, but only screenshots won't make sense!

Answer (score 0):

you can try clean project in build menu.